# Woocommerce REST API only user access their data

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I need to make a mobile application for a Wordpress based e-commerce site.
I'm researched the WordPress and  Woocommerce REST api.

What I want to do is briefly;
To authenticate with username and password via REST API.

if the verification is successful, look  previous orders etc.

**So only the user needs to access the data about himself!**

how is this done ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Woocommerce users or customers are actually Wordpress users

Method POST: You can achieve this in lot of ways.

1st method is:

It's not specific for WooCommerce but also for all WordPress login and sign up

**Sign up end point:**
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users

**Login end point:**
https://example.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token

Comment: I need to create Api Key. Accessing all data with this api Key.